# Lethargic hen with yellow poop

Tags: health, defecation, chickens

I've noticed an unusually lethargic hen this morning, she's even allowed me to pick her up which is incredibly rare for her. Looking around I've noticed some pretty awful looking yellow poop which I think is hers:

Click the box to reveal. Warning for gross image.

> [image]

I've brought her inside with fresh water with VermX in it and some fresh food. Any suggestions as to the cause or treatment suggestions?

Thanks in advance

**UPDATE**

A week later and she's still very poorly, hardly eaten or drunk a thing since. I'm feeding her some water/VermX daily and she seems to be showing some signs of improvement but she's still a long way off.

**UPDATE** 19th June
It was pretty apparent today that she was not going to be making a recovery and to avoid any further suffering she has been put down. I don't think I ever discovered the cause of her illness but would still welcome any suggestions that you might have.

Comment: I am sorry for your loss :( thanks for updating.